# Ignore Last row in CSV file as part of BigQuery External table command

Tags: google-bigquery

I have about 40 odd csv files, comma delimited in GCS however the last line of all the files has quotes and dot

```
”.
```

So these are not exactly conformed csv schema and has data quality issue which i have to get around

My aim is to create an external table referencing to the gcs files and then be able to select the data.

example:

```
create or replace dataset.tableName 
options (
  uris = ['gs://bucket_path/allCSVFILES_*.csv'],
  format = 'CSV',
  skip_leading_rows = 1,
  ignore_unknown_values = true
)
```

the external table gets created without any error. however, when I select the data, I ran to error

"error message: CSV table references column position 16, but line starting at position:18628631 contains only 1 columns"

This is due to quotes and dot ”. at the end of file.

My question is: is there any way in BigQuery to consume to data without the LAST LINE. as part of options we have skip_leading_rows to skip header but any way to skip to last row?

Currently my best placed option is to clean the files, using sed/tail command.

I have checked the create or replace external table options list below and have tried using ignore_unknown_values but other than this option i don't see any other option which will work.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_external_table_statement

Comment: Hi @Bihag Kashikar If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below work around:

I tried with pandas and removed the last record from the csv file.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import storage

df=pd.read_csv('gs://samplecsv.csv')
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('new_table')

df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_ref).result()
```

For more information you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations) which mentions the limitation for loading csv files to Bigquery.

Comment: I ended up cleaning the files on gce using sed '$d'